# Finds Keywords in Log Files

Tags: c, programming-challenge, functional-programming

This is my first project in C and I wanted a more experienced person's insight on how I made the whole program. Just looking for feedback it works how I want it to. The Github is [here](https://github.com/cobb208/logfindAssignment). Thank you so much for the feedback!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dbg.h"

#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 100

int get_file_char_count(FILE *f, char *filename);
int searchForKeyword(char *keyword, char *check_string);
int findLogFilename(char *filename);
int setIsOr(int argc, char *argv[]);
char** logFileNames();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    check((argc == 0), "Arguements required, please enter the search terms you want to look for in the log\nUse the -o to search for terms in one file.");

    unsigned int is_or = setIsOr(argc, argv); // set the and/or operator from -o flag
    FILE *fp;

    
    // Gets all file names in the log folder that end with .log
    char **logfile = logFileNames();
    check(logfile == NULL, "Failed to open directory and find log files!");
    
    int i = 0;
    while(logfile[i] != NULL)
    {

        char f_path[100];
        strcpy(f_path, "./log/");
        strcat(f_path, logfile[i]);


        fp = fopen(f_path, "r");
        int file_length = get_file_char_count(fp, logfile[i]);

        rewind(fp);

        char *file_contents = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_length); // dynamically allocated because of file size
        fgets(file_contents, file_length, fp); // write the stream to the variable

        if(is_or)
        {
            int j = 1; 
            for(j = 1; j < argc; j++)
            {
                int result = searchForKeyword(argv[j], file_contents);
                if(result == 0) {
                    printf("Match has been found in file: %s\n", logfile[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            int j = 1;
            int found_all = 0; // bool to hold if all words were found in file
            for(j = 1; j < argc; j++)
            {
                int result = searchForKeyword(argv[j], file_contents);
                if(result == 0) {
                    found_all = 1;
                } else {
                    found_all = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found_all)
                printf("Match has been found, for all words, in file: %s\n", logfile[i]);
        }
        

        free(file_contents);
        fclose(fp);

        i++;
    }

    free(logfile);

    return 0;

error:
    return -1;
}


int get_file_char_count(FILE *f, char *filename) 
{
    int returnVal = 0;
    char cursor = ' ';

    while(cursor != EOF)
    {
        cursor = fgetc(f);
        returnVal++;
    }

    return returnVal;
}

int searchForKeyword(char *keyword, char *check_string)
{
    regex_t regex;

    int reg_setup;
    int reg_return_result;

    reg_setup = regcomp(&regex, keyword, 0);
    reg_return_result = regexec(&regex, check_string, 0, NULL, 0);

    return reg_return_result;
}

int findLogFilename(char *filename)
{
    regex_t regex;

    int reg_setup;
    int reg_return_result;

    reg_setup = regcomp(&regex, ".log", 0);
    reg_return_result = regexec(&regex, filename, 0, NULL, 0);

    return reg_return_result;
}

int setIsOr(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int ret_int = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "-o") == 0)
        {
            ret_int = 1; // sets the or flag to true
        }
    }

    return ret_int;
}


char** logFileNames() {
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    int isLog = 1;

    char** retArr;
    
    d = opendir("./log");
    check(d, "Could not open");

    int fileCount = 0;

    if(d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            isLog = findLogFilename(dir->d_name);
            if(isLog == 0)
            {
                fileCount++;
            }
        }

        retArr = malloc(sizeof(*retArr) * fileCount);
        check_mem(retArr);

        rewinddir(d);

        int logFilePos = 0;
        while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            isLog = findLogFilename(dir->d_name);
            if(isLog == 0)
            {
                retArr[logFilePos] = dir->d_name;
                logFilePos++;
            }
        }

        closedir(d);

        retArr[logFilePos + 1] = NULL;

        return retArr;

    }
    return NULL;
    

error:
    closedir(d);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Some things are missing from this question.  First, what is this code supposed to *do*, and what do the program arguments mean?  Secondly, what's in `"dbg.h"`?  It would be very helpful to have the definitions available, for reviewers who wish to test the code.

Comment: There's a github link in the question that contains the source. dbg.h is the `check` macro, mostly.

Answer (score 2):

## Pick a style

You write:

```
int get_file_char_count(FILE *f, char *filename);
int searchForKeyword(char *keyword, char *check_string);
```

You are mixing `snake_case` with `camelCase` names for your functions. I suggest that you stick with a single naming case for categories of names, so that all functions will use the same style. Pick one and use it everywhere.

## Parse your args

Instead of writing a function to look for a single command line arg, write a function to parse and configure all the args. Ideally, you will use an argument-parsing library, even if it's just `getopt`.

## Add a command line arg `-d DIR` to specify the log directory

This shouldn't be hard once you've picked an arg parsing library.

## Don't throw away work you've already done

You write:

```
char **logfile = logFileNames();
...
while(logfile[i] != NULL)
{
    char f_path[100];
    strcpy(f_path, "./log/");
    strcat(f_path, logfile[i]);
```

But you have already computed the log file paths in your `logFileNames` function. Instead of repeating this work, have that function do it for you. Find a log file, construct the path, allocate memory using `malloc` or `strdup`, and pass that to the user. (This is in keeping with your **functional-programming** tag, as well.

## Keep all the code in a single function at the same level of abstraction

You write:

```
    fp = fopen(f_path, "r");
    int file_length = get_file_char_count(fp, logfile[i]);
    rewind(fp);

    char *file_contents = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_length); // dynamically allocated because of file size
    fgets(file_contents, file_length, fp); // write the stream to the variable
```

I think you'll be disappointed with how that comes out. But ignoring that, you're doing operations at a low level (`fopen, rewind`) and at a high level (`get_file_char_count`). Don't do that.

Instead, write nice high-level functions to do *all* the work. If you want to know the size of a file, pass in the name and expect a `size_t` result to come back. Let the function do the `fopen` (if it needs to, which it does not).

Also, have a look at the `stat()` function. (Which may be some variant of `_stat` on Windows. [Ask the Duck.](https://duckduckgo.com/))

Similar suggestions apply to getting the file's contents - once you have the contents, you don't need the file pointer, so leave that inside the function. In fact, getting the file size is part of getting the contents. So `main` should not know about the size at all:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool match_all_search_words = ... parse command line ...
const char ** search_words = ... parse command line ...

const char ** log_files = list_log_files(log_dir);

for (int i = 0; log_files[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    const char * log_file = log_files[i];
    const char * text = read_file_contents(log_file);

    if (match_all_search_words) {
        if (all_words_in_text(search_words, text)) {
            report_match(log_file);
        }
        else {
            report_failure(log_file);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (any_words_in_text(search_words, text)) {
            report_match(log_file);
        }
        else {
            report_failure(log_file);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bug: failure to read entire file**

`fgets(file_contents, file_length, fp);` only reads up to a *line*.  Research `fread()`.

**Bug: insufficient allocation**

`fileCount` does not account for the appended `NULL`.

```
// retArr = malloc(sizeof(*retArr) * fileCount);
retArr = malloc(sizeof *retArr * (fileCount + 1));
...
retArr[logFilePos + 1] = NULL;
```

**Bug: 257 vs 256**

`int fgetc()` returns 257 different values.  Saving that into a `char  cursor` will lose information.  Use `int cursor;`

**Avoid buffer overflow**

`strcat(f_path, logfile[i])` risks overflowing the buffer.

```
    char f_path[100];
    //strcpy(f_path, "./log/");
    //strcat(f_path, logfile[i]);

    // Pedantic alternate
    int len = snprintf(f_path, sizeof f_path, "%s%s", "./log/", logfile[i]);
    check(len >= 0 && len < sizeof f_path, "Log file too big");
```

**File length + 1?**

`int get_file_char_count()` returns the file length plus one.  Not a problem as the allocation needed that +1 anyways for `fgets()` to append a *null character*.

File length may exceed `INT_MAX`.  Perhaps use `unsigned long long` or `uintmax_t`?

**Looking for option**

Why check `argv[0]`, the program name?

Why continue checking if found?

Alternate:

```
int setIsOr(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-o") == 0) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

**Alternate `get_file_char_count()`**

For expediency, read a chunk at a time.

```
#define CHAR_COUNT_BUF_N 1024
intmax_t get_file_char_count(FILE *f) {
  if (f == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  rewind(f);  // Let us start at the beginning, clear error flag
  intmax_t char_count = 0;  
  char buf[CHAR_COUNT_BUF_N];
  size_t length;
  while((length = fread(buf, 1, CHAR_COUNT_BUF_N, f) > 0) {
    char_count += length;
  }
  if (ferror(f)) {
    char_count = -1;
  }
  rewind(f);
  return char_count;
}
```

Usage

```
intmax_t file_length = get_file_char_count(fp);
check(file_length >= 0 && file_length < SIZE_MAX, "File length trouble");

size_t file_length_size = (size_t) file_length; 
char *file_contents = malloc(file_length_size + 1);
check(file_contents, "Out of memory");

size_t length = fread(file_contents, 1, file_length_size, fp);
file_contents[file_length_size] = '\0';  // Append a 0 to form a string
check(length == file_length_size, "Read problem");
```

Answer (score 0):

## `malloc()` can return a null pointer

This code hides Undefined Behaviour:

> ```
>     char *file_contents = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_length); // dynamically allocated because of file size
>     fgets(file_contents, file_length, fp); // write the stream to the variable
> ```

We need to ensure that `file_contents` isn't a null pointer before we pass it into `fgets`.

Also, multiplying by `sizeof (char)` is pointless, as that cannot be anything other than 1 (`sizeof` gives results in units of `char`).